# file path for uploading in web server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm very new in web developing. I'm developing a website by using HTML, jQuery, JavaScript, PHP and MySql. On my website I have an option for uploading images, and I'm using this code:

```
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "c:/wamp/www/upload/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]
);
```

This code is for moving the image to `c:wamp/www/upload/upload/`.   How can I achieve this on web server after hosting my website?

Comment: Use a relative path. In fact, you should never really use absolute paths unless you *have* to.

Comment: Is path provide by host provider?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know which hosting provider you're using. If you have an uploads folder in the root directory where you place your web files you would do `move_uploaded_file($file, getcwd() . "/uploads")` to move it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply give path of that folder.suppose the upload folder in the same directory of your uploading file script than you have to do just like that:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                            "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

and if if it is out side of the script file than just use this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                                "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Hence no need to give path from root.

Answer (score 1):

when you upload your files in the local , `do not give "c:/wamp/www"`. Instead give the path relative to the file, like `"../upload/"`.

For example if you have placed your php script file in `"upload/include/"` folder and you would like to upload an image in `"upload/images/"` folder, use `"../images/"` while uploading the files.

Answer (score 0):

Does your web host provide shared or dedicated hosting?

I'm guessing shared, and so you'd probably have a directory path like /htdocs/upload or something similar. Hard to say without knowing what your web host is like.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for the dynamic path retrieval.

Try this,

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```